# How to disable Jinja2 for sections of template with {}?

Tags: python, jinja2

I added a facebook button to my page by copying/pasting the code they supply on their website.

It looks like this:

```
"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={{fbapp_id}}&link={{link_url}}&message={{share_message|urlencode}}&display=popup&redirect_uri={{link_url}}
```

As you can see, it's got the `{}` in there that `Jinja` looks for. However, being that I *don't* want any of the above code replaced with anything, is there something I can add into my template which tells `Jinja` to ignore everything between the delimiters?

Python Handler:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENV.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(None))
```

Comment: maybe instead of copying their code into the source of your template, it might make better sense to insert it as a substitution, add a `{{ facebook_button }}` in a template someplace.  If they change the code on you, you'll have an easier time updating it everywhere, that way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can usually find that information [in the documentation, under "Escaping"](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping) or similar. In this case, you can either output the delimiter with a variable expression:

```
{{ '{{' }}
```

Or you can use the `raw` block, for longer stretches of code:

```
{% raw %}
    <ul>
    {% for item in seq %}
        <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endraw %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is old but I recently had the same issue. If you setup Jinja2 Environment to use undefined=jinja2.DebugUndefined it will ignore missing parameters and leave them as if a new Jinja template. Useful for say multi-stage parsing and u can run logging as well to know when variables have not been defined:

```
import logging
from Jinja2 import DebugUndefined

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
undefined_logging = jinja2.make_logging_undefined(logger=logger, base=DebugUndefined)
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader, undefined=undefined_logging)
print(jinja2.from_string("Hello {{ worldarg }}")

This will result in a logger message such as
[date time] WARNING [<module>:lineno] Template variable warning worldarg is undefined
Hello {{ worldarg }}
```

Template in will have jinja rendered for passed parameters but unaltered for undefined. NOTE: This will unlikely resolve missing templates or macros defined by the routine though but standard {{ x }} types should be logged and unaltered. *Logging is also subject to how its configured as well!

Options also exist for StrictUndefined (results in exception and template processing to stop) or Undefined results in parameters passed to be removed and fields blank where expected without errors being returned to calling function.

Answer (score 0):

For ansible:

```yaml
myvar: !unsafe "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={{fbapp_id}}&link={{link_url}}&message={{share_message|urlencode}}&display=popup&redirect_uri={{link_url}}"
```